# How can we enable sending an invite email when we create an new azure active directory user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've created Azure Active Directory and also verify its Domain for my directory.

However, when I create a user with under its domain, it doesn't send an invite email to the user's email. So I had to personally send an email with the password and ask the new user to access portal.azure.com.

The new user is not a guest user(external user, B2B). So it's not kind of inviting external directory user.

My questions is, Does the Azure Active directory have such feature sending an invite email to newly create user? if so, how can I enable it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To invite the user by sending the email, you could use the POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations in [MS graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json


{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "sendInvitationMessage": true,
  "invitedUserType": "Member", //If you want to invited the user as the member in the aad
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

And the required permissions:
[image]

For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0).